# Do not indent second paragraph after macro was used

Tags: indentation

I defined a macro that I occasionally use at the beginning of sections. After this macro has been used, I do not want the first `real' paragraph (which technically is the second paragraph) to be indented. However, I can only achieve this by omitting any new lines between the macro and the first paragraph. Is there a more elegant way?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\note}[1]{
\begin{flushright}
\textit{#1}
\end{flushright}
}

\section{First section}

First paragraph is correctly NOT indented.

\section{Second section}

\note{My Note}
First `real' paragraph is correctly NOT indented.

\section{Third section}

\note{My Note}

First `real' paragraph should NOT be indented, but IS.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you leave an empty line, it will be the 2nd paragraph. You can use `\noindent`, if you wish.

Comment: I am aware of this fact and the corresponding workarounds. I was wondering whether there is some way to tune macro `\note` to achieve the `\noindent` effect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the commands used by `\section` to suppress indentation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\note}[1]{%
\begin{flushright}
\textit{#1}
\end{flushright}\par\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading
}
\makeatother

\section{First section}

First paragraph is correctly NOT indented.

\section{Second section}

\note{My Note}
First `real' paragraph is correctly NOT indented.

\section{Third section}

\note{My Note}

First `real' paragraph should NOT be indented, and ISN'T.

\end{document}
```

Comment: So easy! +1 :-)

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly. Although I do not quite understand why (i.e. I do not know/understand what these commands do).